# Unable to Login (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: permissions, users, chmod, chown

I'm having a weird issue. When I put my password using my account (ramiz) on the login screen of GUI, a blink of screen and it take me back to the login screen. I tried with Guest user and it is logging me in. I also tried `Ctrl+ATL+F1` to switch to command mode and try to login there with `sudo -s`. And give my login id (ramiz) and password there it successfully logged me there in the command mode.

I remember I ran few `chmod/chown` command which cause me this issue. Before this happened everytime I launch Terminal I got a error msg of permission denied which is something like "`bash: XXXXX Permission denied`". I also lost rights on `.bashrc` file which I think happened after I ran those `chmod/chown` commands.

Please, help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo chown -R ramiz /home/ramiz` and `sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ramiz` should do the trick.

If you cannot run these commands from your user, boot into recovery mode (hold right shift during POST and when the grub menu is shown select the recovery mode (second line)), when you get a menu, remount everything rw, and select netroot. You will be dropped to the root shell, where you can execute the commands without sudo.

Comment: did it work? Can you log in?

Comment: you're a champ! it is works as you say! thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered with the same issue and my friend suggested me a solution. He told me to change the ownership of home and fortunately it helped me . You can find the solution here

[Solution for Ubuntu login problem – Bouncing back to login screen](http://technicalrepository.com/solution-for-ubuntu-login-problem-bouncing-back-to-login-screen/)

From that post:

> On your login screen, press ALT + CTRL + F1
>   It will open the terminal based interface.
>
> Login with your user-name and password.
>
> Once you logged in, just enter the following command.
>
> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
>
> Then logout and press CTRL+ALT+F7 to login into GUI desktop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.